# How do I make my redirect include the name instead of an ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, configuration, routes

I'm using Rails 5.1.  In my controller, I would like to redirect to my "show" method like so

```
redirect_to(@organization)
```

but I would like the URL to appear as

```
/organization/organization_name
```

instead of

```
/organization/primary_key_id
```

How do I set this up?  I already have a field "name" in my Organization model.

**Edit:** As requested, this is the index method of my `PagesController` ...

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  # Should be the home page
  def index
    worker_id = params[:worker_id]
    worker = Worker.find_by_id(worker_id)
    if worker && worker.organization
      redirect_to(worker.organization)
    else
      render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404", layout: false, status: 404
    end
  end

end
```

**Edit:** My `config/routes.rb` file

```
  resources :organizations, :only => [:show] do
    post :update_work
    get :get_work
    get :mine
    get :poll
    post :submit
    get :home
    get :terms_of_use
  end
```

Here's the `app/model/stratum_worker.rb` file

```
class StratumWorker < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :organization_worker
  has_one :organization, :through => :organization_worker
```

Comment: you can use the [Friendly ID](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem

Comment: Ya that answer wont work with your set up.  You might want to share the `PagesController` code as well.

Comment: Could you also include the OrganizationsController and the show method there? I suspect that is where your `missing required keys: [:id]` is coming from.

Comment: Wouldn't that be coming from routes?  I  mean, the error suggests it is not even executing any code in the controller because it doesn't know how to invoke the proper method.  Maybe I'm wrong on that.  My routes are posted in teh question if that is indeed the issue.

Comment: Have you tried adding `puts url_for(worker.organization)` and see that it is generating what you expect?

Comment: The URL is "http://www.example.com/organizations/MyString1".  That's definitely what I intended (string instead of number).  The error is complaining about not finding an ID.  So how do I tell my routes that the path should have a string ID instead of a numeric id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a post [here](https://hackernoon.com/using-custom-slugs-for-rails-urls-500eb3f58f3c) detailing exactly this a while ago. Most of my answer will be from there. The relevant Rails documentation for this is [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters).

**Quick definitions:**

- **Slug:** part of the URL to identify the record, in your case `organization_name`
- **Primary key:** a unique identifier for database records. This usually is and should be `id`.

#### Summary

If you type `organization_path(@organization)`, it'll automatically use the `id` attribute in the URL. To adjust to using `organization_name`, you'll need to make 2 changes:

1. Override the route params in your `routes.rb` file.
2. Override the `to_param` method in the model

#### 1. Override The Route Params

At the moment, if you run `rails routes` your routes look like so:

```
organizations       GET    /organizations(.:format)                     organizations#index
                    POST   /organizations(.:format)                     organizations#create
new_organization    GET    /organizations/new(.:format)                 organizations#new
edit_organization   GET    /organizations/:id/edit(.:format)            organizations#edit
organization        GET    /organizations/:id(.:format)                 organizations#show
                    PATCH  /organizations/:id(.:format)                 organizations#update
                    PUT    /organizations/:id(.:format)                 organizations#update
                    DELETE /organizations/:id(.:format)                 organizations#destroy
```

The `edit_organization` and `organization` paths use `id` as a parameter to lookup your organization.

Use this to override the route params

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :organizations, param: :organization_name
end
```

Now `rails routes` will show that your routes look like so:

```
organizations       GET    /organizations(.:format)                                    organizations#index
                    POST   /organizations(.:format)                                    organizations#create
new_organization    GET    /organizations/new(.:format)                                organizations#new
edit_organization   GET    /organizations/:organization_name/edit(.:format)            organizations#edit
organization        GET    /organizations/:organization_name(.:format)                 organizations#show
                    PATCH  /organizations/:organization_name(.:format)                 organizations#update
                    PUT    /organizations/:organization_name(.:format)                 organizations#update
                    DELETE /organizations/:organization_name(.:format)                 organizations#destroy
```

#### 2. Override The Model Params

By default `organization.to_param` will return the `id` of the organization. This needs to be overridden, do this by modifying your Model:

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  def to_param
    organization_name
  end
end
```

#### Conclusion & Warning

You can now continue using your redirects and forms as usual, but instead of the route using the `id`, it'll now use the organization name.

Also, good luck with your mining pool! Lemme know which coin you're mining and I might join!

Also, I didn't cover this because it isn't a part of your original question, but, you should ensure that the `organization_name` is unique! Not only should you add a uniqueness constraint `validates :organization_name, uniqueness: true` in the mode, you should also enforce it at the database level in your migration.

#### Addendum 1: Customizing for routs

When your routes are defined as so:

```
  resources :organizations, :only => [:show] do
    post  'update_work'
    get   'get_work'
    get   'mine'
    get   'poll'
    post  'submit'
    get   'home'
    get   'terms_of_use'
  end
```

Your routes will be as so:

```
 organization_update_work POST   /organizations/:organization_id/update_work(.:format)                                    organizations#update_work
    organization_get_work GET    /organizations/:organization_id/get_work(.:format)                                       organizations#get_work
        organization_mine GET    /organizations/:organization_id/mine(.:format)                                           organizations#mine
        organization_poll GET    /organizations/:organization_id/poll(.:format)                                           organizations#poll
      organization_submit POST   /organizations/:organization_id/submit(.:format)                                         organizations#submit
        organization_home GET    /organizations/:organization_id/home(.:format)                                           organizations#home
organization_terms_of_use GET    /organizations/:organization_id/terms_of_use(.:format)                                   organizations#terms_of_use
             organization GET    /organizations/:id(.:format)                                                             organizations#show
```

Changing the `param` like so:

```
  resources :organizations, :only => [:show], param: :organization_name do
    post  'update_work'
    get   'get_work'
    get   'mine'
    get   'poll'
    post  'submit'
    get   'home'
    get   'terms_of_use'
  end
```

Will change your routes to

```
 organization_update_work POST   /organizations/:organization_organization_name/update_work(.:format)                     organizations#update_work
    organization_get_work GET    /organizations/:organization_organization_name/get_work(.:format)                        organizations#get_work
        organization_mine GET    /organizations/:organization_organization_name/mine(.:format)                            organizations#mine
        organization_poll GET    /organizations/:organization_organization_name/poll(.:format)                            organizations#poll
      organization_submit POST   /organizations/:organization_organization_name/submit(.:format)                          organizations#submit
        organization_home GET    /organizations/:organization_organization_name/home(.:format)                            organizations#home
organization_terms_of_use GET    /organizations/:organization_organization_name/terms_of_use(.:format)                    organizations#terms_of_use
             organization GET    /organizations/:organization_name(.:format)                                              organizations#show
```

Which should work totally fine with your redirect.

Comment: So you define, "resources :organizations, param: :organization_name" in the routes file, which I assume pertains to the "show"  method of my controller.  But what about the other routes taht I listed in my question?  How do I get them all to play together?

Comment: @Dave I've added an addendum to the answer, but I recommend rewriting and simplifying your question to make it easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

OK, if you are not interested to use any gem then you can without gem like

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
   def to_param  # overridden
      organization_name
    end
end
```

in this case, you need to make sure the `organization_name` name is unique, for uniqueness the `organization_name` you can use validation like this

```
validates_uniqueness_of :organization_name
```

then the model will look like this

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
    validates_uniqueness_of :organization_name

    def to_param  # overridden
      organization_name
    end
end
```

and now to the controller using `find_by_organization_name(params[:organization_name])` instead of `find(params[:id])`.

**Second Option**

You can not change anything to your controller if used like this in just model

```
class Model < ApplicationRecord
    def to_param  # overridden
      organization_name
      "#{id} #{organization_name}".parameterize
    end
end
```

then the URL looks like this `/10-microsoft`.

See this [**`to_param`**](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param) method. The complete reference of with gem or without gem [**`Rails Friendly URLs`**](https://gist.github.com/cdmwebs/1209732)

[**RailsCasts.com**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast) created an episode for Pretty URLs with FriendlyId, can you check it out for getting the idea.

**From Comment**

I don't think what's going on but sure something wrong with the relationship, can you check like this

```
redirect_to(worker.organizations.first)
#=> OR
redirect_to organization_path(worker.organizations.first.id)
```

**Update**

I think `worker.organization` are missing somehow, would you try like this?

```
if worker && worker.organizations.present?
   redirect_to(worker.organizations.first)
....
```

the `present` method making sure `worker.organizations` not blank.

> I don't know about the relationship, you can try like this and let me know what's happening if it's not working then I strongly recommend to post the models with relationship concept.

**Update 2 after question update**

At first, you don't need the `through` relationship because it uses too [**`Many To Many`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) relationships. Your relationship is [`One To One`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one) then your model will look like this

```
class StratumWorker < ApplicationRecord

    has_one :organization_worker
....
```

<del>has_one :organization, :through => :organization_worker</del>

`organization_worker.rb` file like this

```
class OrganizationWorker < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :stratum_worker 

    #=> Add code what you need like for URL which was the actual motive in this post
....
```

Then the action looks like this

```
def index
    worker_id = params[:worker_id]
    worker = StratumWorker.find_by_id(worker_id)
    if worker && worker.organization_worker.present?
      #redirect_to(worker.organization_worker)
      redirect_to organization_path(worker.organization_worker)
    else
      render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404", layout: false, status: 404
    end
end
```

and the show action

```
OrganizationWorker.find(params:id)
```

I think the problem will solve now. If still, you getting errors then please read the [`One To One`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one) relationship again & again until clearing the relationship concept.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Ipmlementing eitehr of tehse options results in teh same error I listed in my question -- "missing required keys: [:id]".

Comment: I don't think what's going on but sure something wrong with the relationship, can you check like this `redirect_to(worker.organization.last)`

Comment: Good thought but when I substitute taht, I get the error "NoMethodError: undefined method `last' for #<Organization:0x00007f96e5e451a0>" on the line "redirect_to organization_path(worker.organization)"

Comment: Have you used `id` like `object.id`

Comment: You mean do "redirect_to organization_path(worker.organization.id)"?  Tried that and got the same error, "ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show" ... missing required keys: [:id]"

Comment: @Dave See the ***Update*** section in the answer

Comment: Regarding the udpate, I posted the model.  I don't have "organizations", which is why I had "if worker && worker.organization".  So I get a 'NoMethodError: undefined method "organizations"' error when I try your code.  Notwithstanding, the error is complaining about no route matching, so isn't this a routing problem?

Comment: Hello, @Dave see this ***Update 2 after question update*** section, try to like this. Hope it will solve.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help with this.  But one question -- why did you change "redirect_to(worker.organization)" to "redirect_to(worker.organization_worker)"?  I don't want to invoke the OrganizationWorkerController -- I don't even have one for that.  I want to invoke the OrganizationController.  Also you think my routes are just fine?

Comment: Don't worry you can change this like `redirect_to organization_path(worker.organization_worker)`

Comment: Thanks but I think the problem is my routes.rb file.  I don't think its right.  I did try your solution above but got the last routing error.

Answer (score 1):

Method that is called under the hood for id generation is `to_param`

so in your case to get your desired result you should add this to your `Organization` class:

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  ...

  def to_param
    name
  end

  ...
end
```

**!!!WARNING!!!**  - since Rails is also using the parameter on the other side (e.g. in show method `Organization.find(params[:id])` uses the URL id), now it will be `params[:id] == "some_organization_name"` so change your instance lookups accordingly - in `show` action for example use `Organization.find_by!(name: params[:id])` and so on

As for your routing error - make sure that `worker.organization` is not `nil`.

Comment: You'll also want a uniqueness constraint on `name` and, depending on what is allowed in `name`, you might want to add a `:constraints` on the routes to avoid confusion with formats and the like.

Comment: @Kkulikovskis, thx but I still get the same error ("No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"organizations"}, missing required keys: [:id]").  I have added the code of my PagesController into my question.

Comment: @Dave Does it work if you do `redirect_to organization_path(worker.organization)` ?

Comment: It results in the same "ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches ... missing required keys: [:id" error.

Comment: @Dave did you check if worker.organization is not nil? if you put debugger in and do `worker.organization` does it return an instance of `Organization`?

Comment: Yes, in my posted code, I have "if worker && worker.organization".  The error occurs on that "redirect_to" line.  Per my comment to the other guy, isn't this a routing error?  The language talks about "no route matching" but I'm pretty bad with Rails so I may be misinterepreting that error.

Answer (score 1):

There is a gem friendly_id that does exactly what you are asking for: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

You add,

```
gem 'friendly_id'
```

Then `bundle install` and run `rails generate friendly_id` and `rails db:migrate`

to your Gemfile and,

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

to your model then,

```
class OrganizationController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = Organization.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

to your controller.

This prevents the issues you can run into in Kkulikovskis answer where you have to make sure that you are looking things up correctly.

Comment: This results in the error, "NoMethodError: undefined method `slug' for #<Organization:0x00007f910669f868>"

Comment: Hi @Dave, did you look athte friendly id readme and run its setup scripts? I'll update my answer to include that.

Comment: No, I hadn't done that.  So I went ahead and did that and now I'm back at that familiar error that occurred for all the other answers, "ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches ... , missing required keys: [:id]"